# ECMAScript: Where can we find specification about accessibility of let/const variables

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2017

Within the [ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0), where can we find a clear specification on why `let` and `const` are not accessible outside of *Lexical Environments* created with *BlockStatements* (as opposed to variables declared with `var`)?

If *BlockStatements* now create [new lexical environments](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-lexical-environments), then `let` and `const` declarations should not create variables accessible outside that lexical environment, but `var` variables should. I am trying to understand where exactly that behaviour is specified in the latest ECMAScript specification.

**From [13.3.1 Let and Const Declarations](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-let-and-const-declarations):**

> let and const declarations define variables that are scoped to the running execution context's LexicalEnvironment. The variables are created when their containing Lexical Environment is instantiated but may not be accessed in any way until the variable's LexicalBinding is evaluated.

**From [13.3.2 Variable Statement](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-variable-statement):**

> A var statement declares variables that are scoped to the running execution context's VariableEnvironment. Var variables are created when their containing Lexical Environment is instantiated and are initialized to undefined when created.

As seen, both variable declarations create variables when their containing *Lexical Environment* is instantiated. Which, in the case of a *BlockStatement* is when the compiler enters the block.

**From [8.3 Execution Contexts](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-execution-contexts):**

> LexicalEnvironment and VariableEnvironment components of an execution context are always Lexical Environments

Comment: It's just that `var`s get created and initialised when a function (or global or eval) scope is entered while `let`s and `const`s are created when any scope is entered. It doesn't explicitly state anywhere that they are *not* created and accessible before.

Comment: Because new VariableEnvironments are only created for functions

Comment: @Bergi Thanks. *Scope* is not really used by the specification though. Do you mean that `var` variables are only created when *Lexical Environments* are created for functions? If so, how would it be possible to create `var` variables outside of functions? I am trying to understand it, solely equipped with the ECMAScript specification.

Comment: @JonasW Interesting, thanks. I will digest this a bit and revert with any doubts.

Comment: @JonasW. I've been turning the spec upside down, but have a hard time spotting that VariableEnvironments are only created for functions. Could you perhaps add an answer showing what steps in the spec you follow to reach said conclusion?

Comment: I would recommend reading 'ECMA-262-5 in detail' section here  http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you saw in the description of `var`, it is scoped to the running execution context's `VariableEnvironment`.  There is a top level `VariableEnvironment` and then a new one is created [when you enter a function](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-variable-statement) and then in [this part about Execution Contexts](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-execution-contexts), it says this:

> The LexicalEnvironment and VariableEnvironment components of an execution context are always Lexical Environments. When an execution context is created its LexicalEnvironment and VariableEnvironment components initially have the same value.

So, at the start of a function, the LexicalEnvironment and VariableEnvironment are one and the same.

Then, down in [13.2.13 Runtime Semantics: Evaluation Block: { }](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-block-runtime-semantics-evaluation), you can see that a new `LexicalEnvironment` is created when you enter the block and the prior one is restored when you leave the block.  But, there is no mention of a new `VariableEnvironment` when you enter or leave a block (because that stays constant within the function).

So, since `let` and `const` are scoped to the LexicalEnvironment in which they are declared and that is local to a block, it would not be accessible outside the block.

But, `var` is scoped to the `VariableEnvironment` which is only created and scoped to the whole function, not to a block.

`let` and `const` variables can't be accessed outside their LexicalEnvironment because their definitions are not in the scope hierarchy as soon as the execution context leaves their block (as soon as you leave the block, their LexicalEnvironment is essentially popped off the stack and is no longer in the scope search chain for the interpreter to find variables).

---

When the specification adds this:

> The [`let` and `const`] variables are created when their containing Lexical Environment is instantiated but may not be accessed in any way until the variable's LexicalBinding is evaluated.

This means that you are denied access to them even in their own Lexical Environment until their definition is evaluated.  In layman's terms, this means they are not hoisted to the top of their scope like `var` is and therefore cannot be used until after their definition.  This is implemented by not initializing a `let` or `const` variable in the `LexicalEnvironment` until its statement runs and the [`GetBindingValue()`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-global-environment-records-getbindingvalue-n-s) operation which looks up a variable will see that it is not yet initialized and will throw a `ReferenceError`.  `var` variables are initialized immediately to `undefined` so they do not cause this `ReferenceError`.

You can see how this works in this code:

```
let x = 3;

function test() {
    x = 1;
    let x = 2;
    console.log("hello");
}
test();
```

At the `let x = 3` line a variable `x` is initialized in the outer LexicalEnvironment.

Then, when you call `test()`, at the start of that function, a new LexicalEnvironment is created, the new declaration for `x` in this block is placed into that new `LexicalEnvironment`, but not yet initialized.

Then, you get to the `x = 1` statement.  The interpreter looks up `x`, finds it in the current `LexicalEnvironment`, but it is uninitialized, so it throws a `ReferenceError`.

---

Per the question in your comment:

> I've been turning the spec upside down, but have a hard time spotting that VariableEnvironments are only created for functions. Could you perhaps add an answer showing what steps in the spec you follow to reach said conclusion?

You have to just go through all the places in the spec where a `VariableEnvironment` is created and you will find that the only places this happens is the beginning of a function execution and at the top level.

For example, here's one on those places: [PrepareForOrdinaryCall](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-prepareforordinarycall).  There are a few others.

But, no place does it ever describe this happening for the start of a block, only the start of a function.

The way these specifications are written, they describe when things do happen, not when they don't happen (which makes some logical sense), but it means to prove something doesn't happen, you have to fail to find anywhere that says it does happen.

Comment: @Magnus - I added a section to the end of my answer on the question in your latest comment.

Comment: That's incredibly helpful, thank you so much! I am heavily overdue on sleep, so will let it digest a bit over night and go through in detail tomorrow. This definitely deserves a thorough study. Just a quick initial question: Where did you see that there is a top level VariableEnvironment? I think I need to understand how the JS engine parses the code, i.e. how execution contexts are created as it works its way from top to bottom of the source code. Would that be: "15.1.10 ScriptEvaluation (scriptRecord)": http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-scriptevaluation ?

Comment: I was a bit quick on the trigger in the above comment. Following your suggested approach, I see "Set the VariableEnvironment of scriptCxt to globalEnv." in "15.1.10 ScriptEvaluation (scriptRecord)". It is also done in these "IteratorBindingInitializations". Is that related to the Iterator Protocols (i.e. iterables and iterators)?

Comment: One related question I have been battling: Are *Lexical Environments* only of importance to (i.e. only relate to) *execution contexts*? I see each function object also stores a link to its own enclosing environment (9.2 ECMAScript Function Objects). I guess that might enable running execution context to search for a specific *Environment Record* in outer *Lexical Environments* (all the way to the *global environment*). Additionally, I guess the spec says somewhere that functions inside other functions loose access to their outer *Lexical Environment*, as `this` then becomes the global object.

Comment: @Magnus - I'm not sure about the first part of your comment yet, but functions inside of functions don't access their LexicalEnvironment via `this`.  They get it through a chain of `LexicalEnvironments`.  When you call a function, the new LexicalEnvironment is pushed onto the start of the chain and resolving a variable name is done by searching that chain in order.  Resolving a variable has nothing to do with `this`.  `this` is used for `this.someVar`. Keep in mind that one can use various tools to control the value of `this` for a function call such as `.call()`, `.apply()`. It's not lexical.